# checking if more elements of array have same value of key , if they have remove one?

Tags: javascript

so I've tried everything that i know. Using map and filter, prototypes. Didn't work. .

```
[{"color":"black","type":"bmw"},{"color":"gray","type":"golf"}, {"color":"red","type":"bmw"}, {"color":"black","type":"mercedes"}]
```

So what I want to achieve, is when i do ajax, with javascript, to check if two or more object have same value for type, if there is for example two or more bmw-s, remove others and and push just one object with bmw type. Hope i am clear enough.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to keep only one element of each type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function removeDuplicates(arr) {
  var alreadyExist = {};           // hash object to keep track of elemnt that have already been encountered
  var indexes = [];                // array of indexes that will be removed
  arr.forEach(function(o, i) {     // for each object o in arr
    if(alreadyExist[o.type])       // if the type of the object o at index i already exist
      indexes.push(i);             // mark its index i to be removed later
    else                           // if not
      alreadyExist[o.type] = true; // then mark the object as found so other ones will be removed
  });
  
  // for each index in the indexes array
  for(var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
    arr.splice(indexes[i] - i, 1); // remove the object at that index ( - i because the array arr is continually changing. Its length decrease every time we remove an item)
}

var array = [{"color":"black","type":"bmw"},{"color":"gray","type":"golf"}, {"color":"red","type":"bmw"}, {"color":"red","type":"bmw"}, {"color":"red","type":"bmw"}, {"color":"black","type":"mercedes"}];

removeDuplicates(array);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

don't remove elements, create a filtered Array:

```
var yourArray = [{"color":"black","type":"bmw"},{"color":"gray","type":"golf"}, {"color":"red","type":"bmw"}, {"color":"black","type":"mercedes"}];

var cache = {}, 
    filteredArray = yourArray.filter(({type}) => type in cache? false: (cache[type] = true));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

It's non destructive, more performant and even simpler and shorter.

**Edit:** And even without modern features:

```
var filteredArray = yourArray.filter(function(item){
        return item.type in this? false: (this[item.type] = true);
    }, {/* the cache-object */}); //abusing `this` to pass the cache object
```

Comment: @Kinduser, the only "modern" thing here is the fat arrow, oh, and using Object destructuring to get the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of which types are already present in your array with an object, then only push into new array those that are not present:

```
var vehicles = [{"color":"black","type":"bmw"},{"color":"gray","type":"golf"}, {"color":"red","type":"bmw"}, {"color":"black","type":"mercedes"}];
var uniques = [];
var types = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (!types[a[i].type]) { uniques.push(a[i]); }
  types[a[i].type] = true;
}
//uniques = [{"color":"black","type":"bmw"},{"color":"gray","type":"golf"}, {"color":"black","type":"mercedes"}];
```